# couchbase python sdk ascii exception

Tags: python-2.7, scrapy, couchbase

First of all, this is the exception

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\middleware.py", line 62, in _process_chain
        return process_chain(self.methods[methodname], obj, *args)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\defer.py", line 65, in process_chain
        d.callback(input)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 383, in callback
        self._startRunCallbacks(result)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 491, in _startRunCallbacks
        self._runCallbacks()
    --- <exception caught here> ---
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 578, in _runCallbacks
        current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
      File "D:\ScrapyProjects\General_Spider_code_version_4\General_Spider_code_version_4\pipelines.py", line 14, in process_item
        connection.set(fileName, dict(item)) #write the item to the couchbase database
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\couchbase-1.2.5-py2.7-win-amd64.egg\couchbase\connection.py", line 331, in set
        persist_to, replicate_to)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\couchbase-1.2.5-py2.7-win-amd64.egg\couchbase\_bootstrap.py", line 99, in _json_encode_wrapper
        return json.dumps(*args, ensure_ascii=False, separators=(',', ':'))
      File "C:\Python27\lib\json\__init__.py", line 250, in dumps
        sort_keys=sort_keys, **kw).encode(obj)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\json\encoder.py", line 210, in encode
        return ''.join(chunks)
    couchbase.exceptions.ValueFormatError: <Couldn't encode value, inner_cause='ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 5: ordinal not in range(128), C Source=(src\convert.c,131), OBJ={'bathrooms': 1.0, 'furnished': 'No', 'ad_title': 'Large Studio For Rent in IMPZ just 45K/4chqs(KK)', 'agent_fees': -1, 'size': 550.0, 'category': 'Apartment', 'company_rera_number': '12913', 'agent_company': 'AL ANAS REAL ESTATE BROKER', 'ded_licence_number': '700590', 'source': 'dubizzleproperty', 'location': 'UAE \xe2\x80\xaa>\xe2\x80\xaa Dubai \xe2\x80\xaa>\xe2\x80\xaa IMPZ International Media Production Zone ; 3.1 km from Meadows Town Centre \xc2\xa0', 'image_links': [u'http://87421a79fde09fda7e57-79445249ccb41a60f7b99c8ef6df8604.r12.cf3.rackcdn.com/4_async/2015/2/18/73ff34e2a38c7b104401c9e5c54b03628971053f/main.jpeg', u'http://87421a79fde09fda7e57-79445249ccb41a60f7b99c8ef6df8604.r12.cf3.rackcdn.com/4_async/2015/2/18/24ec831f6b4afb47fecc1c3e0991cf3090c90c24/main.jpeg', u'http://87421a79fde09fda7e57-79445249ccb41a60f7b99c8ef6df8604.r12.cf3.rackcdn.com/4_async/2015/2/18/77fee11394090aaea2d668cfe2754b92d6e36264/main.jpeg', u'http://87421a79fde09fda7e57-79445249ccb41a60f7b99c8ef6df8604.r12.cf3.rackcdn.com/4_async/2015/2/18/5d4113319ccbabcdd65b0ffe7302da59b374b5fe/main.jpeg', u'http://87421a79fde09fda7e57-79445249ccb41a60f7b99c8ef6df8604.r12.cf3.rackcdn.com/4_async/2015/2/18/8070689f309759d5860e97aa35d3f0eac425dc1d/main.jpeg', u'http://87421a79fde09fda7e57-79445249ccb41a60f7b99c8ef6df8604.r12.cf3.rackcdn.com/4_async/2015/2/18/8e86702847e69d485d147629dd2e48e1ad831e63/main.jpeg'], 'latitude': -1, 'description': 'Central A/C & Heating , Balcony , Shared Pool , Built in Wardrobes , Walk-in Closet , Shared Gym , Security , Built in Kitchen Appliances', 'bedrooms': 'Studio', 'rent_is_paid': 'Quarterly', 'action': 'Rent', 'link': 'http://dubai.dubizzle.com/property-for-rent/residential/apartmentflat/2015/2/18/large-studio-for-rent-in-impz-just-45k4chq-2/?back=ZHViYWkuZHViaXp6bGUuY29tL3Byb3BlcnR5LWZvci1yZW50L3Jlc2lkZW50aWFsL2FwYXJ0bWVudGZsYXQv&pos=1', 'longitude': -1, 'property_reference': '', 'yearly_cost': 45000.0, 'agent_mobile': -1, 'posting_date': '2015-02-19'}>
```

I am trying to store a dictionary on a couchbase. i am using this code

```
connection.set(fileName, dict(item))
```

to transfer the `item` to dictionary. as you see from the error message. i have a unicode values, which is according to python sdk couchbase is fine, could you help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your values are not unicode. Keep in mind that a `str` object containing valid unicode escape sequences does not automatically make it "Unicode" in Python parlance. You need to ensure the strings are properly Unicode.

This seems to work with the normal `json.dumps()` function (without any arguments); whereas the python client passes (by default) the `ensure_ascii=False` parameter to decrease the data size (JSON itself can be in UTF-8 encoding, and is not limited to ASCII).

Thus, a workaround may be to set your own encoding function for JSON which does not pass the `ensure_ascii` parameter; like so:

```
import json
import couchbase

couchbase.set_json_converters(json.dumps, json.loads)
```

Though this workaround is not recommended as it may inflate your document size slightly.

Comment: isn't there a way to reduce the size? like just making a specific attirbute as utf8 and the others are ascii? give me a link (links) to more details please

Comment: The JSON spec allows unicode values to be expressed either in their native form (that is, in a supported unicode encoding), or in pure 7-bit ASCII using "Escape" clauses; so for example the letter ש may be encoded either as `\xd7\xa9` (native UTF-8; total size of 16 bytes), or as `\u05e9` (ASCII-safe escape sequence, 6 bytes). Passing `ensure_ascii=False` will always disable the latter (6 byte) form, while `ensure_ascii=True` will use the escape form whenever a character is outside the 7 bit range

Comment: so could you give me an example (or a link description) to how to apply these things? until now this is my code to insert the data to couchbase `from couchbase import Couchbase
        import couchbase
        couchbase.set_json_converters(json.dumps, json.loads)
        connection = Couchbase.connect(bucket='default') connection.set(fileName, dict(item))`

Comment: plus what is this `set_json_converters` for? the offical description is not clear at all http://www.couchbase.com/autodocs/couchbase-python-client-1.2.0/html/api/convertfuncs.html

Comment: I think the description is very clear in what it does. In any event, just applying the snippet should be good enough. The `set_json_converters` function is a global, so you should ideally call it right after you import the module. The rest of your code remains the same. Also, please fix your code and understand how Python deals with Unicode. I would highly recommend against using `set_json_converters` (which is usually used to install a _faster_ serializer)