# python what is the different of size when replacing json.dump by json.load

Tags: python, json, couchbase

#### Background:

I am working on python sdk to insert some data to couchbase.

When I tried to insert the data using the `set` method like this:

```
connection = set(key, document)
```

I got exception states that the data is unicoded and it is not ascii. I solved that problem using this:

```
couchbase.set_json_converters(json.dumps, json.loads)
```

#### My question:

will that solution affects the size of the data that is being inserted to couchbase?

Plus, could you give me a little explanation about the different of joson.dumps and json.loads. I tried to search over internet and I found that json.dump is for encoding while json.loads is for decoding, but i didn't understand

#### After the comment

I did this:

```
print "First Approach is using JSON loads instead of JSON dumps"
import json
import sys
d = "roma"
sizeBefore = sys.getsizeof(d)
print "size of d  = {0}".format(sizeBefore)

dumped = json.dumps(d)
sizeAfter = sys.getsizeof(dumped)
print "size with json.dumps = {0}".format(sizeAfter)

loads = json.loads(dumped)
sizeLoad = sys.getsizeof(loads)
print "size with json.loads = {0}".format(sizeLoad)

print "-------------------------"
print "Second approach is decoding the string as UTF-8"
sizeBeforeDecode = sys.getsizeof(d)
print "Size before applying decode = {0}".format(sizeBeforeDecode)

d=d.decode("utf-8")
sizeAfterDecode = sys.getsizeof(d)
print "Size after applying decode = {0}".format(sizeAfterDecode)
```

The result is:

```
First Approach is using JSON loads instead of JSON dumps
size of d  = 37
size with json.dumps = 39
size with json.loads = 58
-------------------------
Second approach is decoding the string as UTF-8
Size before applying decode = 37
Size after applying decode = 58
```

What does that mean please?

Comment: dumps will create a valid json string from your dict, loads basically  takes that string and makes it a dict. I would not worry too much about the size. `dumped = dumps(d)` a dict in a shell and then use `loads(dumped)` and you will see the difference

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I will try to use your analysis. but did you mean to do this: `d = [(key1, value1), (key2, value2)] dumped = dumps(d)` ? and how can I notice the difference ?

Comment: yes that will work, if you want to check the size use sys.getsizeof before and after

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I will try it and I will come back to you

Comment: you can also make the strings unicode as you create them,  `s ="foo".decode("utf-8")` .

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I updated my question, could you check please?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I updated the code again to add the decode thing, could you check please? many thanks

Comment: You are seeing the size of the object in bytes

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.getsizeof

Comment: @PadraicCunningham yes i got the idea, but isn't that what I should look for? the size of the object that I wanna insert to the couchbase, or i should look for something else?

Comment: why are you so worried about the size? Does couchbase want unicode or ascii? Doing a json.loads will convert to unicode.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham i worry about the size because i will have A LOT of data every hour being inserted to the couchbase. and yes the json.loads solve the problem, but also the decode solve it too. i wanna know which one is better (json.load or decode)

Comment: if you are processing the strings anyway then you may as well decode and just pass them.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the title question, this is like comparing apples to oranges. `json.dumps` will convert a Python object to a JSON representation, and `json.loads` will convert a JSON representation to a Python object. The `set_json_converters` simply accepts a *pair* of an encoder and decoder function (so you basically need to set them both at the same time, even if you only want to replace one of them).

To address your *real* issue:

As mentioned in the original post here ([couchbase python sdk ascii exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28593263/couchbase-python-sdk-ascii-exception)), the *proper* solution is to ensure your input (or in this case, its constituent key/values) are either:

1. 7-Bit ASCII Python `str` objects
2. Python `unicode` objects

*Ideally*, you should ensure that any data you intend to treat as "Text" (i.e. non-'binary' data, or data which you intend to encode into non-'binary' formats (such as JSON)) should be converted into a `unicode` object as *early as possible*. Unfortunately in Python2 (see below), it is very easy to accidentally mix up the two -- often resulting in discovering problems deep in the processing chain, rather than early on.

The `set_json_converters` "solution" is merely just a hack so that your code can work (sub-optimally) until it is actually fixed. To fix it, you need to properly sanitize and normalize your input. Currently your input is a dictionary which has "byte" values which are *not* Unicode. Yes, the specific values in your *may* be interpreted as valid UTF-8 sequences, but Python does not care about this, and therefore functions which expect valid "Unicode" inputs will fail.

I *strongly* suggest you read http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html for a very thorough, practical, and correct explanation of Unicode handling in Python.